# How to disable href that is not clicked in loop?

Tags: javascript, html

[image]

As the picture of template, when i click one of the link between `number1` to `number3`, i want to disable the other links that are not clicked, for instance, `number2` were clicked then `number1` and `number2` will be disable by this style `pointer-events: none; cursor: default;` and when i click on restart link, every link will be able to click again.

This is my template code using flask as a web framework.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body>

      {% for number in range(5) %} 
        <a href="#"> number1 </a> &nbsp;
        <a href="#"> number2 </a> &nbsp;
        <a href="#"> number3 </a> &nbsp;
        <a href="#"> restart </a> &nbsp;
      <br>
      {% endfor %}


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why don't you code it in a simpler way? Like you could make it clickable only on hover and everyone is disabled by default ;)

Comment: and you don't even need a restart button

Comment: @Orange Orange thank you for response, i will looking on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I grouped your links in the rows with the name attribute, is this what you're looking for mate? because you gave no sample of what you tried etc..

```
#Flask
{% for number in range(5) %} 
    <a href="#" name="{number}" onClick="disable(event,{number})"> number1 </a> &nbsp;
    <a href="#" name="{number}" onClick="disable(event,{number})"> number2 </a> &nbsp;
    <a href="#" name="{number}" onClick="disable(event,{number})"> number3 </a> &nbsp;
    <a href="#" onClick="enable({number})"> restart </a> &nbsp;
    <br>
{% endfor %}

#CSS
.disabled{
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
}

#JS
function disable(event,number){
    event.preventDefault();
    var el=document.getElementsByName(number);
    for(i = 0;i<el.length;i++){
        if (e[i] != event.target)
            el[i].classList.add('disabled');
    }
    location.href = event.target.href;
}

function enable(number){
    var el=document.getElementsByName(number)
    for(i = 0;i<el.length;i++)
        el[i].classList.remove('disabled');
}
```

Consider changing restart to a button(or ditching it per Orange's suggestion) and using
[Event listeners](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp)

Comment: thank you for response, this is very close to my answer, but when i click some number of each row it will disable all number of that row, actually i just want to disable only the other number that are not clicked of that row. So how can i do that.